# Calendar Alarm While Machine Sleeps

Tags: ical, automator, sleep-wake, calendar

I have a handful of Calendar Alarms I created in Automator to run at various times on my MacBook Pro (mainly overnight).  However, it looks like if the machine is sleep then the Calendar Alarm is simply skipped.  Is there a way to set it to execute any missed Calendar Alarms when the machine wakes?

(Note that iCal used to do this with events that would "run a script" as a reminder.  But Mountain Lion seems to have deprecated that reminder type, so I'm trying Calendar Alarms from Automator now.)

Comment: Same question. Anyone?

Comment: I too have this question. I've searched quite extensively, but I can't find anything (possibly because the search results are jammed by posts about power nap, or about using alerts to wake the compute).

Comment: Hello, did you figure out a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In Mountain Lion, the Reminders application is able to do this. You create a reminder, then open it up and check "remind me on a day." You can then set a time for the reminder. If your computer is asleep at the scheduled time, the reminder will show up next time it's awake.

Comment: How do I set the Reminder (or Task) to run a script or an application?  I'm not seeing that option in the interface, is it hidden somewhere?